# Dropdown menu to display over DIV

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a simple CSS dropdown menu, the function is correct but I am having issues when I place it inside a holding DIV. The menu expands  inside the DIV and adds scrolling bars.

I have tried hiding the overflow and positioning the elements but it  has no effect:

**[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/TJTR/bnbb8dhk/1/)**

```css
body
{
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 50px 150px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropdown
{
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
.dropdown li
{
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    /*padding: 15px 20px;*/
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.dropdown li:hover
{
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
.dropdown li ul
{
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.dropdown li ul li
{ 
    display: block; 
    color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.dropdown li ul li:hover
{
    background: #666;
}
.dropdown li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 1px 1px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) inset;border: 1px solid #DDD; overflow: auto; background-color: #FFF; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px; width:100%; height:50px;">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Section1
            <ul>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help, absolute positioning on dropdown helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this: **[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/bnbb8dhk/4/)**

```
.dropdown {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 1px 1px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) inset;border: 1px solid #DDD;
background-color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 10px;
width:100%;
height:50px; position:relative;">
```

Add `position relative to div` and remove `overflow` property. then `add position:absolute to dropdown`. Hope this helps !!

**Code With Snippet below**

```css
body
{
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 50px 150px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropdown
{
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.dropdown li
{
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    /*padding: 15px 20px;*/
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.dropdown li:hover
{
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
.dropdown li ul
{
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.dropdown li ul li
{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.dropdown li ul li:hover 
{
    background: #666;
}
.dropdown li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 1px 1px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) inset;border: 1px solid #DDD;background-color: #FFF;text-align: center;border-radius: 10px;width:100%;height:50px; position:relative;">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Section1
            <ul>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the `.dropdown` a `position absolute;` as well.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnbb8dhk/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

please try this one:

please Add `.dropdown` css like this:`position absolute;`

**[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/bnbb8dhk/6/)**

```css
body
{
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 50px 150px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center; 
}
.dropdown
{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
.dropdown li
{
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    /*padding: 15px 20px;*/
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.dropdown li:hover
{
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
.dropdown li ul
{
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.dropdown li ul li
{ 
    display: block; 
    color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.dropdown li ul li:hover
{
    background: #666;
}
.dropdown li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 1px 1px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) inset;border: 1px solid #DDD;overflow: auto;background-color: #FFF;text-align: center;border-radius: 10px;width:100%;height:50px;">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Section1
            <ul>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
                <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```